# Mouse Keys Cursor won't appear

Tags: keyboard, mouse-pointer

I have been stuck with a recent issue that I can't figure out. I have to be able to not use a mouse with a computer that I am setting up on a cart for our school. The computer running on it is running the latest version of Ubuntu. I have set up mouse keys to run on it, but then here's where I run into the issue.

Upon startup, I login, and you can't do anything with the mouse keys unless the cursor is visible. In order to make it visible, you have to move the actual mouse a little and then I can use mouse keys. Kinda defeats the purpose of going without a mouse, aye?

Is there any way to make the mouse cursor appear on startup without having to mess with the normal mouse at all?

Thanks for any aid that any of you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort of a workaround, but you could install the `xautomation` package which provides `xte`. xte allows you to move the mouse (as well as simulate other inputs to the x server).

see http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte

by including `xte mousermove 1 1` in your `~/.xinitrc`, it may move the mouse when you log in and allow it to remain visible. I have not tested this, but it seems like it should work. Or bin d this to a key, run a script, something along those lines..

Comment: I was able to find the file and enter it into it, but that did not allow the mouse to show. I also tried putting it into the startup application. It didn't work either. I haven't tried binding it to a key, yet, but I wanted to tell you my progress. Just tried, key binding doesn't work

Comment: That was a lie, experimenting with the command line. It makes the mouse move, but it doesn't make it appear. I can control the mouse after that, but I can't see the cursor.

Comment: a few ideas, but really just grabbing at straws.. changing vts using alt+ctrl+F2,F3,etc and change back. try `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse` from a terminal. ensuring that you have the proper graphics drivers installed, and if so try switching between open source or proprietary drivers. AFAIK the mouse should just "be there" when you start up, hence the odd suggestions

Comment: Running this command in terminal fixed the issue. "gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false" Thanks for your help, I'll mark you as correct.